# How to run south manage.py commands from PyCharm?

Tags: django, django-south, pycharm, django-manage.py

Is it possible to run the manage.py south commands from PyCharm?
If it is possible, how can it be done?
I can't find the documentation about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see [PY-2859](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/PY-2859).

> If south is added to INSTALLED_APPS migrate command should be in the list.  It can be absent in case of PyCharm doesn't understand the structure of your project properly.

Comment: Turns out that if you import the settings from another module PyCharm doesn't recognizes it.